# modify field value in a crossfilter after insertion

Tags: crossfilter

I need to modify a field value for all records in a crossfilter before inserting new records.
The API doesn't say anything about it. Is there a way to do that ?
Even if it's a hack that would be really useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, the data array is held as a private local variable inside the crossfilter function so there's no way to get at it directly.

With that said, it looks like Crossfilter really tries to minimize the number of copies of the data it makes.  So callback functions like the ones passed into [crossfilter.dimension](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension) or [dimension.filter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_filter) are passed the actual records themselves from the data array (using the native Array.map) so any changes to make to the records will be made to the main records.

With that said, you obviously need to be very careful that you're not changing anything that is relied on by the existing dimensions, filters or groups.  Otherwise you'll end up with data that doesn't agree with the internal Crossfilter structures and chaos will ensue.

Answer (score 0):

The cool thing about .remove is it only removes entries that match the currently applied filters.  So if you create a 'unique dimension' that returns a unique value for every entry in your dataset (like an ID column), you can have a function like this:

```
function editEntry(id, changes) {
    uniqueDimension.filter(id); // filter to the item you want to change
    var selectedEntry = uniqueDimension.top(1)[0]; // get the item
    _.extend(selectedEntry, changes); // apply changes to it
    ndx.remove(); // remove all items that pass the current filter (which will just be the item we are changing
    ndx.add([selectedEntry]); // re-add the item
    uniqueDimension.filter(null); // clear the filter
    dc.redrawAll(); // redraw the UI
}
```

Comment: Sorry to get back to that so long after the fact but I'm playing with `crossfilter` again now :). I assume `ndx` is the original crossfilter object right ?

Answer (score 0):

At the least you could do a cf.remove() then readd the adjusted data with cf.add().